# Continue calendar time after timepick

Tags: android, calendar, timepicker

How do I make a calendar's time to run after I pick in timepicker? It seems calendar's time does not run if I pick. If I pick 1:00PM it will be 1:00PM forever. how do i make it 1:01PM after 1 minute? what i did was after timepicker, i set it to a calendar.

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a user to be able to set a clock using the TimePicker dialog, and have the TimePicker dialog show the previous set time + elapsed time the next time it shows?
This may work for you:

MainActivity.java

```
// class implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener and uses onTimeSet()
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
  //myTime wrapped in Long instead of primitive long so it can be null
  Long myTime;
  int hours, mins;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  //TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener returns here
  @Override
  public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int min) {
    myTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.hours = hour;
    this.mins = min;
  }

  //our xml button onClick method to trigger TimePicker dialog
  public  void timeButtonClicked( View v ){
    //send bundle arguments to fragment if hour/minute previously set
    TimePickerFragment fragment = TimePickerFragment.newInstance( myTime, hours, mins );
    fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
  }
}
```

TimePickerFragment.java

```
public  class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

  public static TimePickerFragment newInstance( Long savedTime, int hours, int mins ){
    TimePickerFragment myFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    //savedTime is Long wrapped so it can be null if not set
    //and thus bundle will not be set if savedTime is null
    if(savedTime!=null){
      args.putLong("savedTime", savedTime);
      args.putInt("hours", hours);
      args.putInt("mins", mins);
      myFragment.setArguments(args);
    }
    return myFragment;
  }

  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    Long savedTime;
    int hoursDiff=0, minsDiff=0;
    int hourOfDay, minute;

    // create a Calendar instance of the current time
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    long currentTime = c.getTimeInMillis();

    // create hourOfDay, minute variables to pass as parameters
    // to the TimePicker dialog. If passed by bundle, use that
    // time and difference otherwise use current time
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();  //NOT savedInstanceState bundle
    if (bundle != null) {
      // unix time in milliseconds since Epoch set
      // by System.currentTimeMillis() by MainActivity.onTimeSet()
      savedTime = bundle.getLong("savedTime");
      // set calendar to passed savedTime + (current time difference)
      long timeDifference = currentTime-savedTime;
      minsDiff = (int)(timeDifference/60000);
      if(minsDiff>60) hoursDiff = (int)(minsDiff/60);
      // hours and mins last set by MainActivity.onTimeSet()
      hourOfDay=bundle.getInt("hours")+hoursDiff;
      minute=bundle.getInt("mins")+minsDiff;
    }
    else {
       // bundle not set, use current time
       hourOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
       minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    }

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog with hourOfDay and minute parameters and return the fragment
    return new TimePickerDialog( getActivity(),
        (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), hourOfDay, minute,
        DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
  }
}
```